# Why does the log stream for AWS EBS not work properly?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The problem with log stream is that:

1. After some time it stops and doesn't show any logs, how to make it non Stop.
2. In Start it shows all of the logs from beginning, how i can i restrict to get from specific time

The command I put is

```
eb logs -g  /aws/elasticbeanstalk/env-name/var/log/web.stdout.log --stream
```

The output I get is like

```
============= i-0b747e9c812f5655e - /aws/elasticbeanstalk/env/var/log/web.stdout.log ===
        
[i-0b747e9c812f5655e] b'Sep  3 13:56:12 ip-172-31-25-226 web: data keep-alive'
        
        
============= i-0b747e9c812f5655e - /aws/elasticbeanstalk/env/var/log/web.stdout.log ==============
        
[i-0b747e9c812f5655e] b'Sep  3 13:57:39 ip-172-31-25-226 web: data keep-alive'
```

I'm getting logs from Twitter application. `data-keep alive` is to keep the connection alive. It works well; when I see the logs from the console it's still generating.

The stream doesn't show up in sequential manner. It shows up incomplete logs and start streaming from there.

```
[i-07917057722df810e] b'Sep  2 10:02:39 ip-172-31-46-9 web: > node index'
[i-07917057722df810e] b'Sep  2 10:02:39 ip-172-31-46-9 web: Visit http://anyweb.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:3000'
    
============= i-0b747e9c812f5655e - /aws/elasticbeanstalk/env/var/log/web.stdout.log ==============
        
[i-0b747e9c812f5655e] b'Sep  3 13:56:12 ip-172-31-25-226 web: data keep-alive'
        
============= i-0b747e9c812f5655e - /aws/elasticbeanstalk/env/var/log/web.stdout.log ==============
        
[i-0b747e9c812f5655e] b'Sep  3 13:57:39 ip-172-31-25-226 web: data keep-alive'
```

In Between there are lots of logs missed.

Comment: What kind of logs do you get on output? Could you attach the example of logs at the moment when it stops?

Comment: It stops randomly and it's slow in retrieving log's. @VadimYangunaev i have attached output.